# "Type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' is not defined." in .Net Web Site

Tags: sql, .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2013, import

I'm trying to get a .NET web site running on a network server, and while everything is set up and running locally on my machine (using IISExpress), when I deploy to a Windows Server 2008 server with IIS installed, I end up getting compilation errors when trying to use an SqlConnection:

> Compiler Error Message: BC30002: Type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' is not defined.

Now, I have both import statements at the beginning of the source file as follows:

> Imports System.Data.SqlClient
>
> Imports System.Data

In the compilation warnings it lists a very strange error:

> Warning: BC40056: Namespace or type specified in the Imports 'System.Data.SqlClient' doesn't contain any public member or cannot be found. Make sure the namespace or the type is defined and contains at least one public member. Make sure the imported element name doesn't use any aliases.

Evidently, the compiler can't find System.Data.SqlClient. The IIS application pool is running .NET 2.0, and my site is targeting 3.5. I'm very new to .NET development, and I'm learning this as I go, but this has me stuck. Am I missing a dependency? Do I need SQL Server Management Studio installed on the server?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 1):

A couple of things

1. Inside your web application you might be missing the reference to *System.Data*

   - Right click on Solution Explorer
   - Add References
   - Click on .NET and find System.Data.dll
2. You may already have a class called SqlConnection (Your own), and there might be an ambiguity. Reference the Sqlclient/SqlConnection class directly  System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection

Comment: 1. When going to add the reference to "System.Data", a dialog pops up telling me "The Web site is already referencing the assembly 'System.Data'". 2. I have it referenced in the code as System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection for every use. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem.
It's easy to solve it.

REPALCE

> using Microsoft.Data.SqlClient;

instead of

> using System.Data.SqlClient;